# Android Studio nullability annoying warning

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, nullable

The problem:

```
@Nullable
private View view;

public doSomethingWithView() {
   checkNotNull(view); //<- this throws NPE if parameter is null
   view.showWarningAboutIssue(); //<- IDE reports about possible null here
}
```

Is there a way to configure the IDE, so that it doesn't report for a possible NPE on the second line?

**UPDATE:**
I'm using **Dagger** `checkNotNull` method which is identical to **Guava** ones. If I change import from **Dagger** to **Guava** my IDE removes the warning.

**UPDATE #2**
With latest update of Android studio I can not reproduce it anymore

Comment: `assert view != null`?

Comment: Sounds like a bug with their infer-nullity system. I suggest you tell them. They probably don't check for the case of NPE's being thrown. It might help if you post a minimal reproducible example, though.

Comment: @michaelsnowden How would someone go about telling them and having the message heard in the fastest manner possible?

Comment: @JossieCalderon creating ticket on Jetbrains issue tracker?

Comment: @EugenMartynov pardon my ignorance, but how would I find the Jetbrains that Android uses?

Comment: Now I don't get you :) You're thinking it is Android specific  issue, or you are trying to take JetBrains position?

Comment: @EugenMartynov Yes I thought it was Android specific issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the following comment before `view.showWarningAboutIssue()` statement:

```
//noinspection ConstantConditions
```

This can also be performed by the GUI : `Alt+Enter` (or "bubblelight" menu), then choose `Assert view!=null` and then `Suppress for statement`:

[image]

Comment: Denis, this trick I know. But question is that AS doesn't analyse function before and doesn't know that on this line NPE is not possible

Comment: Sorry, but your question is on "How to **TEACH** IDE"

Comment: I'm not English native speaker. Could you edit questions so it is clear that I want to teach ide and don't insert these comments everywhere

Comment: I replaced *TEACH* by *CONFIGURE*  (and change a little bit the sentence); I expect it's more clear (I'm not a native English speaker either). My edit has to be reviewed before getting published.